# Is Microsoft's documentation wrong regarding the MergeCall symbol, unicode identifier EA3C?

Tags: uwp-xaml

On Microsoft's documentation page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font it says the MergeCall symbol has unicode identifier EA3C. However, it appears to not work.

Putting in the xaml

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEA3C;"/>
```

produces the unknown block.

Would their documentation be wrong? If so, what is the correct code? And how did you find the correct code?

Info, if it matters, I am on Windows 10 version 1809.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced this issue in 1809 and reported it. But when I tested it in 1903, it displayed well. So you can upgrade your system to 1903 to use it or copy the Segoe MDL2 Assets which is on a higher version of the system(e.g. Control panel -> Fonts -> Segoe MDL2 Assets) and then include it in your project. For example: I include it in Assets and named "segmdl2.ttf". When you try to use the symbol, point FontFamily to it.

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="/Assets/segmdl2.ttf#Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEA3C;"></FontIcon>
```